# Binding some string to an Image

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

We have a WPF project, at some point we want to display a list of compatibles devices. Thoses devices comes from a registry in which different modules(projects) can add their library.

At the end, I'm trying to bind a string with the image to the Source of an an image:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image}"></Image>
```

Currently in "Image", I've this:

```
"/My.Project.Name;Component/Images/SomeImage.png"
```

Please note that :

- "Images" is a folder in the mentionned project
- "My.Project.Name" is only a library project, so it's not the WPF one
- "SomeImage.png" is currently set as "Content".

It's what I found I should use, but currently I get this error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 6 : 'TargetDefaultValueConverter' converter failed to convert value '/My.Project.Name;Component/Images/SomeImage.png' (type 'String'); fallback value will be used, if available. BindingExpression:Path=Image; DataItem='WizardOneChoice`1' (HashCode=56913160); target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource') IOException:'System.IO.IOException: Cannot locate resource 'images/someimage.png'.
   at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.GetStreamCore(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.CachedResponse.GetResponseStream()
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.get_ContentType()
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.SetupDecoderFromUriOrStream(Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, Guid& clsId, Boolean& isOriginalWritable, Stream& uriStream, UnmanagedMemoryStream& unmanagedMemoryStream, SafeFileHandle& safeFilehandle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateFromUriOrStream(Uri baseUri, Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, RequestCachePolicy uriCachePolicy, Boolean insertInDecoderCache)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.CreateFromUriOrStream(Uri baseUri, Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, RequestCachePolicy uriCachePolicy)
   at System.Windows.Media.ImageSourceConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)
   at MS.Internal.Data.TargetDefaultValueConverter.Convert(Object o, Type type, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertHelper(IValueConverter converter, Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8d901984-e023-4063-93af-43c8e3f0826c/wpf-image-source-data-binding-from-a-string?forum=wpf

Comment: In code behind, you have to specify a full [Resource File Pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#resource-file-pack-uris), including the prefix: `pack://application:,,,/My.Project.Name;Component/Images/SomeImage.png`, where `My.Project.Name` is an assembly name. The Build Action of the image files must be set to `Resource`.

Comment: @Clemens Why is it marked as clone? I don't want to have the image in the resource, and my image is in another project. Nothing in the reference  helps me.

Comment: Sorry that the question is not an exact duplicate, but the answer exactly explains what to do. Just with a different folder name, Images instead of Resources.

Comment: @Clemens I disagree, there is no indication on how to reference an external project(which apparently is different since in the given project there is no mention of which project it is used in.

Comment: Changed the duplicate... The important thing is to set the Build Action of the image files to `Resource` and use fully qualified resource file pack URIs.

Comment: @Clemens this is in fact the question I initially refered to. Didn't see the "Update 3"